# Windows 8.1 Store apps minimizing automatically

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app

Almost all my Windows Store apps are minimizing by itself in the app splash screen, then when I click to open it again or press the Windows key + Tab key to maximize it is still at the splash screen and keeps there forever.

Even the Store app is doing that, so I can't install or update my apps.

Does someone know how to fix this problem? What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Windows 8.1 N  (version without Media Player)

I solved this [by installing Windows Media Player](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744).

Comment: Could you develop on how installing Windows Media Player solved this problem?